# How to extract .dfm file from a delphi executable?

Tags: delphi

Is it possible to retrieve .dfm file from a delphi executable. I have inherited Acrobyte projects(Indy Pity Crew) so before I reactivate the website(www.acrobyte.cf) every product must be in order. I have updated others except the three left. So since I have a software that converts .dfm to .pas I can update them. I have seen the software that extracts DFM data from a delphi executable, in form of .rc and .dat but I never been able to add a function that extract the whole DFM file.

How can I extract the whole dfm file of an executable e.g( pet.exe to pet.dfm)?

In other ways I would like to convert rc file to dfm.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Interactive Delphi Reconstructor](https://github.com/crypto2011/IDR), [DeDe](http://www.woodmann.com/collaborative/tools/index.php/DeDe), and [DE Decompiler](http://www.woodmann.com/collaborative/tools/index.php/DE_Decompiler) can all be used to extract DFMs from Delphi EXEs.

Comment: DeDe and DE Decompiler don't work on Acrobyte projects except Interactive Delphi Reconstructor  I will give it a try, hold on I will accept an answer soon.

Comment: Interactive Delphi Reconstructor doesn't export .dfm file. I failed to do it

Comment: Even if someone have idea of binding .rc files together and form .dfm I appreciate that too

Answer (score 0):

Interactive Delphi Reconstructor can save text representation of form. Simply click right button on text representation and copy it to clipboard. Also You can try to save file as Delphi Project for all dfm-files in project.